# Storing multiple selectors in a single variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-on, prop

I have a piece of code that handles clicks on images that represent buttons. If that image is clicked, its corresponding image will appear to the user. By selecting the multiple IDs of the images, the vode below works perfectly fine.

```
$("#content").on('click','#buttonID1, #buttonID2, #buttonID3, #buttonID4', function(){
    var $varThis = $(this);
    var tmpID = $varThis.prop('id').split('ID')[1];         
    $('#imageID'+tmpID).css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

However, I will have a lot more of these IDs to select. So is it possible to store the image's `#buttonID` in a single variable and place that variable inside the `.on()` method? Will they be independently selected?

The code below does not work.

```
var $buttons = $('#buttonID1, #buttonID2, #buttonID3, #buttonID4');
$("#content").on('click',$buttons, function(){
     var $varThis = $(this);
     var tmpID = $varThis.prop('id').split('ID')[1];            
     $('#imageID'+tmpID).css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this what classes are for? Add a class, let's call it `myButton` to all your buttons and then use that as a selector.

```
$("#content").on('click','.myButton', function(){
```

Alternatively, if you insist on using ids, this ought to work:

```
var buttons = '#buttonID1, #buttonID2, #buttonID3, #buttonID4';
$("#content").on('click',buttons, function(){
```

Comment: Im not using classes, because I need to know its corresponding image. So `#buttonID1` corresponds to `#imageID1`.

Comment: @Nuktu: And what part of using classes excludes you from still using the ID? This isn't an either/or proposition.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't see that until now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
var $buttons = $('#buttonID1, #buttonID2, #buttonID3, #buttonID4');

To

var $buttons = '#buttonID1, #buttonID2, #buttonID3, #buttonID4';

  $("#content").on('click',$buttons, function(){
        var $varThis = $(this);
        var tmpID = $varThis.prop('id').split('ID')[1];         
        $('#imageID'+tmpID).css({'display': 'block'});
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use css attribute-starts-with selector for that:

```
$("#content").on('click','button[id^="buttonID"]', function(){
 ...
}
```